# Replace certain value with nan in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data-frame:

```
, overall_score, industry_score
0, 15, -
1, 18, 12
2, - , 1
3, - , -
4, 12, 3
```

For some reason when I run:

```
print(df.isnull().sum())
```

It does not see the '-' as seen in index number 0, 2 and 3 as a nan value, how can I fix this? Because the - does actually mean that there's a missing datapoint.

Result of df.to_dict():

```
{' overall_score': {0: ' 15', 1: ' 18', 2: ' - ', 3: ' - ', 4: ' 12'}, ' industry_score': {0: ' -', 1: ' 12', 2: ' 1', 3: ' -', 4: ' 3'}}
```

Comment: If you have '-' you don't have numbers but strings. Use `pd.to_numeric` or read your data properly from the start.

Comment: Post the results of df.to_dict() to this question.

Comment: @AntonvBR the data has been scraped from a website, I don't control how a website presents their data.

Comment: @PEREZje In that case you need to convert it to numeric.

Comment: you can use `df.replace('-',np.nan, regex=True)`

Comment: @nimrodz it did not seem to replace any of the '-' values

Answer (score 3):

### `read_csv`

Use the `na_values` argument to address the problem while parsing a file.

```
pd.read_csv('test.csv', na_values=['-'], index_col=0, sep='\s*\,\s*', engine='python')

   overall_score  industry_score
0           15.0             NaN
1           18.0            12.0
2            NaN             1.0
3            NaN             NaN
4           12.0             3.0
```

---

### `mask`

This can be useful if columns are of `dtype` `object` and intended to stay so.

```
df.mask(lambda x: x == '-')

   overall_score  industry_score
0           15.0             NaN
1           18.0            12.0
2            NaN             1.0
3            NaN             NaN
4           12.0             3.0
```

Comment: Yes this works. However it makes no sense to not convert columns to numeric as we are dealing with scores (numbers).

Comment: The **`read_csv`** answer addresses how to solve the problem ahead of time.  The **`mask`** answer addresses when columns are strings and `-` is intended to be a null value.  `to_numeric` might be very useful but in this context is a club assuming everything is meant to be numeric.  Even if OP intended it so, it doesn't mean that everyone searching for an answer will have the same situation.

Comment: Ok I buy that and I had the same intention in my comments. But it should be included in your answer as an explanatory text. Don't you agree?

Comment: Sure, it would improve the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You say your data is scraped. But at some point it is read to a dataframe and in that reading process it would be more efficient to pass a dtype = 'float'.

But let us assume you took over that dataframe. In that case use `df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')` to convert your values to numbers (in this process non-valids, e.g. ´-´will be replaced with nan).

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''\
overall_score,industry_score
15,-
18,12
-,1
-,-
12,3'''

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data), sep=',')
print(df.isnull().sum())

#overall_score     0
#industry_score    0
#dtype: int64

cols = ['overall_score', 'industry_score']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
print(df.isnull().sum())

#overall_score     2
#industry_score    2
#dtype: int64
```

Comment: This worked, but I do have some strings in my dataframe that should not be removed, is it possible to only affect certain columns?

Comment: @PEREZje Yes ofc. See update.